# Is it possible to simply turn off a dying SATA1 hard disk without physically disconnecting it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata

I am running Windows 7 on a 2011 HP Compaq 8200 Elite SFF PC.

SATA1 is the boot disk, a solid state disk. I have completely forgotten the original HD SATA0 is still in there and its still circa 2011 file system on the D: and E: drives.

So now the OS is giving dialogs that SATA0 is dying, starting yesterday, and the computer powered down twice since then (something it normally does less than once a year), I assume because of the sick disk.

I don't really have time to pull the PC and get SATA0 physically disconnected.  Is there any way to simply turn it off from the BIOS or OS?  Or do I HAVE to go in there and start pulling wires?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. For example:

Windows

- deactivate the whole device via the device manager in Windows
- turn it offline in the disk management (diskmgmt.msc) in Windows

BIOS (depending on your BIOS features)

- disable the controller port